# Bash Script - cp for loop cant find directory which is definitely there

Tags: bash, loops, for-loop, copy, cp

This is my first post, so let me now if im doing anything wrong!

I'm having a problem in bash trying to use cp in a loop and was wondering if anyone could help? I cant seem to get it to find a directory that is definitely there

I'm trying to take a some .pdf files in a set of similar sub directory paths and copy them to one easy to see file.

Here's what my script looks like:

```
shopt -s globstar

s_dir="C:/Bash Testing/CG SIS Standard Items"

t_dir="C:/Bash Testing/BoxFolder"

REFS=$(find "$s_dir"** -iname "*.pdf" -ipath "*/References/*" -not -ipath "*/Archive/*")


for ref in "${REFS[@]}"
do
    SORTED_REFS="$SORTED_REFS $ref"
done

COPY_REFS=$( "$SORTED_REFS" | sort -u )

echo "$COPY_REFS"

for file in "$COPY_REFS"
do
    cp -v "$file  C:/Bash Testing/BoxFolder/" .
done
```

and this is what GIT bash looks like after i run the script including the results of pwd & ls so you can understand the folder structure a little better.

```
./script.sh: line 47:  C:/Bash Testing/CG SIS Standard Items/00 General/References/CG SiS Standard Items - Material Board.pdf
C:/Bash Testing/CG SIS Standard Items/CG.S.001_Short Rail, 1368mm/References/CG.S.001_Short Rail, 1368mm.pdf
C:/Bash Testing/CG SIS Standard Items/CG.S.002_Short Base/References/CG.S.002_Short Base.pdf
C:/Bash Testing/CG SIS Standard Items/CG.S.003_Square Base/References/CG.S.003_Square Base.pdf
C:/Bash Testing/CG SIS Standard Items/CG.S.004_Long Rail, 1368mm/References/CG.S.004_Long Rail, 1368mm.pdf
C:/Bash Testing/CG SIS Standard Items/CG.S.005_Long Base/References/CG.S.005_Long Base.pdf
C:/Bash Testing/CG SIS Standard Items/CG.S.006_Short Rail, 1528mm/References/CG.S.006_Short Rail, 1528mm.pdf
C:/Bash Testing/CG SIS Standard Items/CG.S.007_Shelf Add On/References/CG.S.007_Shelf Add On.pdf
C:/Bash Testing/CG SIS Standard Items/CG.S.008_Storage Table/References/CG.S.008_Storage Table.pdf
C:/Bash Testing/CG SIS Standard Items/CG.S.009_Nesting Table/References/CG.S.009_Nesting Table.pdf
C:/Bash Testing/CG SIS Standard Items/CG.S.010_Storage Block/References/CG.S.010_Storage Block.pdf
C:/Bash Testing/CG SIS Standard Items/CG.S.011_Long Rail, 1528mm/References/CG.S.011_Long Rail, 1528mm.pdf
C:/Bash Testing/CG SIS Standard Items/CG.S.012_Wall Mounted Frame/References/CG.S.012_Wall Mounted Frame.pdf
C:/Bash Testing/CG SIS Standard Items/CG.S.013_Short Base, Slim/References/CG.S.013_Short Base, Slim.pdf
C:/Bash Testing/CG SIS Standard Items/CG.S.014_Long Base, Slim/References/CG.S.014_Long Base, Slim.pdf
C:/Bash Testing/CG SIS Standard Items/CG.S.015_Mannequin Stand/References/CG.S.015_Mannequin Stand.pdf
C:/Bash Testing/CG SIS Standard Items/CG.S.016_Accessory Unit/References/CG.S.016_Accessory Unit.pdf
C:/Bash Testing/CG SIS Standard Items/CG.S.018_End Rail/References/CG.S.018_End Rail.pdf
C:/Bash Testing/CG SIS Standard Items/CG.S.019_Tall Nesting Table/References/CG.S.019_Tall Nesting Table.pdf
C:/Bash Testing/CG SIS Standard Items/CG.S.020_End Rail Cap/References/CG.S.020_End Rail Cap.pdf
C:/Bash Testing/CG SIS Standard Items/CG.S.022_Wall Mounted Frame Rail/References/CG.S.022_Wall Mounted Frame Rail.pdf
C:/Bash Testing/CG SIS Standard Items/CG.S.023_Wall Mounted Frame Shelf/References/CG.S.023_Wall Mounted Frame Shelf.pdf
C:/Bash Testing/CG SIS Standard Items/CG.S.024_Wall Mounted Frame Top Shelf/References/CG.S.024_Wall Mounted Frame Top Shelf.pdf
C:/Bash Testing/CG SIS Standard Items/CG.S.025_Wall Mounted Frame Large/References/CG.S.025_Wall Mounted Frame Large.pdf
C:/Bash Testing/CG SIS Standard Items/CG.S.026_Wall Mounted Frame Large Rail/References/CG.S.026_Wall Mounted Frame Large Rail.pdf
C:/Bash Testing/CG SIS Standard Items/CG.S.027_Wall Mounted Frame Large Shelf/References/CG.S.027_Wall Mounted Frame Large Shelf.pdf
C:/Bash Testing/CG SIS Standard Items/CG.S.028_Wall Mounted Frame Large Top Shelf/References/CG.S.028_Wall Mounted Frame Large Top Shelf.pdf
C:/Bash Testing/CG SIS Standard Items/CG.S.029_Wall Mounted Frame Face Out Arm/References/CG.S.029_Wall Mounted Frame Face Out Arm REV 1.pdf
C:/Bash Testing/CG SIS Standard Items/CG.S.029_Wall Mounted Frame Face Out Arm/References/CG.S.029_Wall Mounted Frame Face Out Arm.pdf
C:/Bash Testing/CG SIS Standard Items/CG.S.030_Wall Mounted Frame Cabinet/References/CG.S.030_Wall Mounted Frame Cabinet.pdf
C:/Bash Testing/CG SIS Standard Items/CG.S.030_Wall Mounted Frame Cabinet/References/CG.S.030_Wall Mounted Frame Cabinet_NEW DIVIDER.pdf
C:/Bash Testing/CG SIS Standard Items/CG.S.031_Rail Face Out/References/CG.S.031_Rail Face Out REV1.pdf
C:/Bash Testing/CG SIS Standard Items/CG.S.031_Rail Face Out/References/CG.S.031_Rail Face Out.pdf: No such file or directory

cp: cannot stat '  C:/Bash Testing/BoxFolder/': No such file or directory
>> pwd
/c/Bash Testing
>> ls
 {testfile}.txt}  '~bash_profile'   1.txt   2.txt   3.txt   4.txt   5.txt   BoxFolder/  'CG SIS Standard Items'/   script.sh*   test.sh
>> ls 'CG SIS Standard Items'
'00 Account Management'/        'CG.S.009_Nesting Table'/       'CG.S.022_Wall Mounted Frame Rail'/
'00 General'/                   'CG.S.010_Storage Block'/       'CG.S.023_Wall Mounted Frame Shelf'/
'00 Item Archive'/              'CG.S.011_Long Rail, 1528mm'/   'CG.S.024_Wall Mounted Frame Top Shelf'/
'CG.S.001_Short Rail, 1368mm'/  'CG.S.012_Wall Mounted Frame'/  'CG.S.025_Wall Mounted Frame Large'/
'CG.S.002_Short Base'/          'CG.S.013_Short Base, Slim'/    'CG.S.026_Wall Mounted Frame Large Rail'/
'CG.S.003_Square Base'/         'CG.S.014_Long Base, Slim'/     'CG.S.027_Wall Mounted Frame Large Shelf'/
'CG.S.004_Long Rail, 1368mm'/   'CG.S.015_Mannequin Stand'/     'CG.S.028_Wall Mounted Frame Large Top Shelf'/
'CG.S.005_Long Base'/           'CG.S.016_Accessory Unit'/      'CG.S.029_Wall Mounted Frame Face Out Arm'/
'CG.S.006_Short Rail, 1528mm'/  'CG.S.018_End Rail'/            'CG.S.030_Wall Mounted Frame Cabinet'/
'CG.S.007_Shelf Add On'/        'CG.S.019_Tall Nesting Table'/  'CG.S.031_Rail Face Out'/
'CG.S.008_Storage Table'/       'CG.S.020_End Rail Cap'/        'CG.S.032_ Plinths'/
```

Thanks in advance. please let me know if you need more info

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to fix the quoting on "cp". Looks like you want all  files copied to "C:/Bash Testing/BoxFolder/", but the copy specify "." as the target folder.

```
Instead of:
 cp -v "$file  C:/Bash Testing/BoxFolder/" .

Use:
 cp -v "$file" "C:/Bash Testing/BoxFolder/"
```

If you want all files placed into the current folder, replace the 'Testing/BoxFolder/" with "."

**Update 1:**
Bassed on additional information from OP (comments below), looks like the goal is to copy all the files in a tree structure into a single folder. This can be achieved more efficiently using the combined find/xargs/cp.

```
shopt -s globstar

s_dir="C:/Bash Testing/CG SIS Standard Items"
t_dir="C:/Bash Testing/BoxFolder"

find "$s_dir"** -iname "*.pdf" -ipath "*/References/*" -not -ipath "*/Archive/*" | xargs -L50 cp -t "$t_dir"
```

**Update 2: globstar**
On surface, there is no need to use globstar and find. Since find is already is use, globstar and '**' can be removed.

```
s_dir="C:/Bash Testing/CG SIS Standard Items"
t_dir="C:/Bash Testing/BoxFolder"

find "$s_dir" -iname "*.pdf" -ipath "*/References/*" -not -ipath "*/Archive/*" | xargs -L50 cp -t "$t_dir"
```

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. so when i fix the quotation marks i get this in bash

```cp: cannot stat '': No such file or directory```

and when i replace 'Testing/BoxFolder/" with "." i get the same thing (i tried the full stop with and without quotation marks, just to be sure"

any ideas?

thanks again

Comment: On surface, looks like file is set to empty string. See revised answer on how to simplify the script. In particular, I'm not sure that you get any advantage from sorting the file list, or from processing ${REFS[@}

Comment: Can you also clarify where do you want the files to be copied to  - the current folder (.) or a specific folder (Testing/BoxFolder/).

Comment: Hi thanks for getting back to me again. i'm trying to get it to copy to "Testing/BoxFolder/"

update 2 is one of the first ways i tried it. I'm not too hot with xargs and all its options yet though. with update 2 i get a problem where it treats exmpty space as the end of a value and the start of a new one. see below where all the file paths have been split us

```cp: cannot stat 'C:/Bash': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat 'Testing/CG': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat 'SIS': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat 'Standard': No such file or directory
...
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone stumbling across this and looking for an answer:

its seemed as though xargs didnt like multiple files or the files being on new lines...

but -exec works perfectly

here's my code that worked (so annoyingly simple. must have spent about 5 hours fumbling with this)

```
s_dir="C:/Bash Testing/CG SIS Standard Items"
t_dir="C:/Bash Testing/BoxFolder"

find "$s_dir" -iname "*.pdf" -ipath "*/References/*" -not -ipath "*/Archive/*"  -exec cp {} "$t_dir" \;
```